# line plot() takes from 0 to 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, matplotlib, deep-learning

I have the following sample code, where I need to draw 2 lines, as shown in the plot below:

```
original = df[['Date', 'Open']]
original['Date']=pd.to_datetime(original['Date'])
original = original.loc[original['Date'] >= '2020-5-1']

sns.lineplot(original['Date'], original['Open'])
sns.lineplot(df_forecast['Date'], df_forecast['Open'])
```

But when i run this code i got error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[26], line 5
      2 original['Date']=pd.to_datetime(original['Date'])
      3 original = original.loc[original['Date'] >= '2020-5-1']
----> 5 sns.lineplot(original['Date'], original['Open'])
      6 sns.lineplot(df_forecast['Date'], df_forecast['Open'])

TypeError: lineplot() takes from 0 to 1 positional argument but 2 were given.
```

I tried putting x and y at original['Date'], and original['Open'] but I got empty result.

Comment: What is `sns`? Is that `seaborn`?

Comment: See https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html for how to use it.

Comment: You should use `x=` and `y=` in `sns.lineplot(x=original['Date'], y=original['Open'])`. Or, better yet: `sns.lineplot(data=original, x='Date', y='Open')`.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I got it, Please What should I do to get a good model?